# How to print out results based on solution to previous double

Tags: java, loops, switch-statement

I have an assignment and I have a few issues first being when I get the result to my bmi calculation to display the result of my calculation to what it is....underweight <18.5 normal 18.5-24.99 overweight 25.0- 29.99 obese >30.

```
//Calculate BMI
    case 3:
        System.out.println("To calculate BMI please enter weight in kg: ");
        double kilo;
        kilo = userdata.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("You entered " + kilo + "kg. Now enter height in cm: ");
        double height;
        height = userdata.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Thanks!");
        System.out.println("Since you entered " + kilo + " kgs, and " + height + " cms, your BMI is: ");
        double bmi;
        bmi = kilo/height/height * 10000;
        System.out.println(bmi + " which means you are " );
```

My second issue being how would I end up getting this switch statement to run over and over until the user decides to exit the programs. I know it is one of the looped statements however I am hitting a wall with my beginner knowledge.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    int userChoice;
    
    userChoice = choice();
    
    Scanner userdata = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    switch (userChoice) {

    /*********************************************************************************************************************/
    
    //Pounds to Kilograms
    case 1: 
        
        System.out.println("Please enter pounds to convert to kilograms: ");
        double lb = userdata.nextDouble();
        double kg;
        System.out.println("You entered " + lb + " pounds, which is equal to " + (kg = lb * 0.45) + " kilograms. ");
        break;
    
    /*********************************************************************************************************************/ 
    
    //Inches to Centimeters
    case 2:
        System.out.println("Please enter inches to convert to centimeters: ");
        double in = userdata.nextDouble();
        double cm;
        System.out.println("You entered " + in + " inches, which is equal to " + (cm = in * 2.54) + " centimeters. ");
        break;
    
    /*********************************************************************************************************************/     
    
    //Calculate BMI
    case 3:
        System.out.println("To calculate BMI please enter weight in kg: ");
        double kilo;
        kilo = userdata.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("You entered " + kilo + "kg. Now enter height in cm: ");
        double height;
        height = userdata.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Thanks!");
        System.out.println("Since you entered " + kilo + " kgs, and " + height + " cms, your BMI is: ");
        double bmi;
        bmi = kilo/height/height * 10000;
        System.out.println(bmi + " which means you are " );
        
    
    case 4: 
        System.out.println("Exiting the program.");
        
}
    
    
    
    
}

public static int choice() {
    
    //variable for menu selection
    int choice;
    //setup user input
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    /*****************************************************************************************************************/
    
    //User inputs selection from menu
    System.out.println("Please make a selection of out of the following options: ");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("1: Convert pounds to kilograms.");
    System.out.println("2: Convert height in inches to centimeters.");
    System.out.println("3: Calculate BMI display category.");
    System.out.println("4: Exit the program.");
    
    choice = input.nextInt();
    return choice;
    
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

This code runs forever:

```
while (true) {
   // this code keeps being run, over and over.
}
```

If you want 'out', you use the `break;` statement (yes, the same one that gets you out of switches). If you need to break out of 2 things (you'll need to do that here; `break;` would be interpreted as 'hop out of the switch', you want 'hop out of the while that is surrounding the switch'), use labelled breaks:

```
myLabel:
while (true) {
   switch (stuff) {
       case 1: break myLabel;
    }
}
```

or, forget about labelled breaks and just `System.exit()` in there.

Comment: I am just confused as where the while would fall in having two methods I keep running into either repeating the actual selection over and over again but not the menu selection.

Comment: The while loop would go around almost the entire thing. At least around the entire switch block, with the `case 4` option needing to 'break' out of it.